# java6→java8にアップデートしたらXML読み込み時にSAXNotRecognizedExceptionが発生

Tags: java, java8

java6では正常に動いていたXMLの読み込みが、java8にアップデートしたら
以下のようなExcepitonをはきだすようになってしまいました。
同じような現象を経験した方、解法をご存知の方がいましたら、お知恵を拝借できないでしょうか？

```
重大: null
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
```

Comment: XML parser関連のjarのバージョンをあげましょう。特にXercesとimplのjarのバージョン。mavenをお使いならpom.xmlの依存関係などチェックしましょう。

Answer (score 3):

kenji Noguchi様、ありがとうございます。
おっしゃるとおり、Xercesのjarを最新にしたら上手く動かすことが出来ました。

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/downloads.html
http://archive.apache.org/dist/xml/xalan-j/
上記サイトから、xalan-j_2_7_1-bin.zip をダウンロードして
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar
serializer.jar
xalan.jar
これらのファイルを差し替えることで、問題解決をすることが出来ました。

改めて、ありがとうございました。